# Vim printing text at the bottom after executing a command

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

What I am trying to do is to give visual feedback that I have done something . For example, if I mapped a key to do a git pull and refresh, and I want to say something like "Files reloaded"

What function should I use in VIM to print the text in the little line at the bottom after I execute my function? I'm talking about the line at the bottom that says "recording" when you type in 'q'.  If it's not possible (maybe it's reserved from vim only), is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `echo` or `echom` (see their help entries for the difference).